# Zero-knowledge proof of knowledge of a plaintext in exponential ElGamal

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, elgamal-encryption, commitments

Consider the exponential ElGamal cryptosystem over some group $G$ with generator $g$. Let $m$ be a plaintext, and $(R, C) = (g^r, g^m \cdot y^r)$ an encryption thereof for some public key $y$.

Assume a prover $P$ wants to prove knowledge of $m$ to a verifier $V$.

To me, the $C$ of the ciphertext looks a fair bit like a Pedersen commitment to some value $m$ with randomness $r$, $E(m, r) = g^m \cdot h^r$.

Is this a reasonable comparison? If so, would it be sensible to use a ZKPK of a Pedersen commitment to prove knowledge of the plaintext?

Comment: Would you elaborate on "brute force" part please? For ElGamal, one would expect a multiplicative group or a large prime order.

Comment: Agreed. What I meant in this case was that the message set might be limited to one of 'polynomially' many values, as you might encounter in eg a voting scheme (where it might be just two valid values - yes or no).

But I suppose in such a case you would likely end up using a different proof, showing that the vote is a permitted value, anyway - there's a bunch of those floating around in literature.

For the purpose of this question let's assume any member of the group is a valid message, I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: Great, it is the protocol to verify Pedersen commitment for the second part of the ciphertext. Also, Schnorr protocol for the first part. Both protocols must use the same response for $r$.